# Assigning negative value to .scrollLeft jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.map').scrollTop(700).scrollLeft(0);
```

I want to assign a negative value to .scrollLeft but unfortunately when I do, it just acts as if it started on zero.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [`$.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (or CSS positions) for what you are planning to do.

`$.scrollLeft()` always defaults to `0` for negative values. Think of it as a function to move the scrollbar. You can't drag this beyond 0 either.